# TextEdit saves changes to file without prompting when you duplicate

Tags: textedit

I opened a file and modified the contents, then selected duplicate meaning to save the duplicate as a new file. I closed the original, expecting rekect the prompt to save changes... instead it closed the file *with my changes* without any prompting at all. My original file is apparently just gone.

Unless I have found a bug (unlikely) I must be misunderstanding how *duplicate* functions. In lieu of save-as (from Windows world) what is the correct way to achieve the same thing without risking loss of data?

Comment: @user3439894 quite some years I guess I just never came across this... I rarely use TextEdit! You say "by default" does that mean I can change this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**macOS** has for some time now, by default, automatically save changes to a *document* in **TextEdit** without prompting. Make your duplicate first, close the original, then edit the duplicate.

If you want to be prompted, then go to **System Preferences** > **General** and check the **[√]Ask to keep changes when closing documents** *checkbox*.

This works for most all **Apple** *application's* and some *third-party application's*. Some will prompt either way.

Comment: luckily it wasn't an important file (and I had a backup) :)

Comment: @Mr. Boy, BTW It's been like this, and not just in **TextEdit**, since **OS X Mountain Lion**.

Comment: thanks - a bit scary I never knew!